# Allow [django-storages] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a Python library containing file storage backends for Django, supporting many block storage providers, (S)FTP, etc.

I think it'd be useful if there was a tag for [django-storages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-storages), but a very similar tag, [django-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-storage) already exists, referring to Django storage backends in general.

Comment: Wait, it's a *Python* library? That's kind of confusing. Maybe the tag should be [python-django-storages]?

Answer (score 2):

This is now complete. I've created a [python-django-storages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-django-storages) tag and retagged a few of the obvious questions in [django-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-storage) to the new tag, and suggested a minimal tag wiki / excerpt. I'm sure there are couple hundred more questions to retag, though.